# Intermediate variables in Bayesian model for binomial data

Tags: bayesian, binomial-distribution, likelihood, stan

Let us assume we have the data modeled $D|\pi\sim Binomial (N,\pi)$, where we assume $N$ is given throughout. We also have that $\pi|\theta \sim V( \theta )$ where $V$ is a known distribution and $\theta$ is a vector of parameters. Let us assume we know $f(\theta)$ and it is easy to compute.

I tried applying this model through the following process in Stan:

1. Sample $\theta$ from $f(\theta)$
2. Sample $\pi$ from $V(\theta)$ given the above value of $\theta$.
3. Sample $D$ from $Binomial(N,\pi)$.

The following is the code I used in the model part of Stan:

```
theta ~ prior(prior_params);
pi ~ V(theta);
defaults ~ binomial(credits,pi);
```

However, when I run the chains, **the parameters $\theta$ don't seem to respond to the data**. In fact, $f(\theta|D) \approx f(\theta)$. I don't know why this happens, probably due to a misspecification of the model. I think it might have to do with the fact that the likelihood is responding only to $\pi$, this is, $f(D|\pi,\theta) = f(D|\pi)$, but I thought that through the sampling of $\pi|\theta$ the model would "take into account" $\theta$.

Comment: Can you add your Stan code and data?

Comment: What is the functional form of $f(\theta)$?

Comment: What data $D$ do you have?